# Superscript in entry title

Tags: redactor, titles

We launched a site for a scientific publication and they use subscript and superscript in lots of their content. Now they'd like to use in entry titles too..

I know I can set the entry title to be a custom field, but that field would be a rich text field in this case, which is far far far from ideal for a title.

I'm using this plugin to add sub/superscript https://github.com/elliotlewis/Redactor-Extras

Looking to fix this without having to use a rich text field.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can create different Redactor Fields with different settings/plugins. The easiest solution would be to create a redactor field only with your sub/superscript options so users can only insert those 2 things and no other html elements (bold, italic and so on).

You can search for an existing plugin or create your own to disable line breaks as well

Answer (score 1):

A simple option for you would just be to use unicode superscript characters in your `title`s:

http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2070-209F

https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator